# Is there a version of os.getcwd() that doesn't dereference symlinks?

Tags: python, path, symlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get/set logical directory path in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123958/how-to-get-set-logical-directory-path-in-python)

I have a Python script that I run from a symlinked directory, and I call os.getcwd() in it, expecting to get the symlinked path I ran it from. Instead it gives me the "real" path, and in this case that's not helpful. I need it to actually give me the symlinked version.

Does Python have a command for that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Workaround: `os.getenv('PWD')`

Comment: Note that the `PWD` environment variable isn't updated by `os.chdir()`, so it can be inconsistent with `os.getcwd()` even when there are no symlinks at all.

Answer (score 13):

In general this is not possible. `os.getcwd()` calls getcwd(3), and according to [POSIX.1-2008 (IEEE Std 1003.1-2008)](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html):

> The pathname shall contain no components that are dot or dot-dot, or are symbolic links.

`os.getenv['PWD']` is shell-dependent and will not work for example with `sh` from FreeBSD.