# Python subprocess pwd inconsistent when file structure includes alias

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, alias, pwd

When I run the following script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
print(subprocess.check_output(["pwd"]))
```

the result is

> /scratch1/name/Dropbox (NAM)/docs/research/Y2/results/s8

whilst from my Ubuntu terminal, the command

```
pwd
```

yields

> /quake/home/name/docs/research/Y2/results/s8

which is an alias to the first path. Why are they inconsistent?

Comment: did you try `os.getcwd()` ?

Comment: @Frodon
I just tried it. The result is the same as `subprocess.check_output(["pwd"])`.

Comment: what about `os.environ['PWD']` ?

Comment: @Frodon I made a mistake in the question. But os.environ['PWD'] does emulate `pwd` as I originally asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR - Use [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwd)

---

You could use [`os.path.realpath`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath) to turn a path containing symlinks into the physical path, resolving any symlinks:

```
~/src/stackoverflow $ mkdir targetdir
~/src/stackoverflow $ ln -s targetdir symlink
~/src/stackoverflow $ cd symlink
~/src/stackoverflow/symlink $
~/src/stackoverflow/symlink $ python

>>> import os
>>> import subprocess
>>> import shlex
>>>
>>> path = subprocess.check_output('pwd').strip()
>>> path
'/Users/lukasgraf/src/stackoverflow/symlink'
>>> os.path.realpath(path)
'/Users/lukasgraf/src/stackoverflow/targetdir'
```

---

There is also the `-P` option to the `pwd` command that enforces this.

From the `pwd` man page (on OS X):

> The pwd utility writes the absolute pathname of the current working
>   directory to the standard output.
>
> Some shells may provide a builtin pwd command which is similar or
>   identical to this utility.  Consult the builtin(1) manual page.
>
> ```
>  The options are as follows:
>
>  -L      Display the logical current working directory.
>
>  -P      Display the physical current working directory (all symbolic
>          links resolved).
>
>  If no options are specified, the -L option is assumed.
> ```

So this would work too:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(shlex.split('pwd -P'))
'/Users/lukasgraf/src/stackoverflow/targetdir\n'
>>>
```

---

However, the best option is to use [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwd) from the Python standard library:

```
>>> os.getcwd()
'/Users/lukasgraf/src/stackoverflow/targetdir'
```

It's not explicitly documented, but it seems to already resolve symlinks for you. In any case, you will want to avoid shelling out (using `subprocess`) for something that the standard library already provides for you, like getting the current working directory.

Comment: Can `os.getcwd()` (or another standard library method) be used to get the logical current working directory? (I.e. emulate `pwd -L`).

Comment: No, `os.getcwd()` takes no arguments as you can see from the documentation.

Comment: Also see: [Is there a version of os.getcwd() that doesn't dereference symlinks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542803/is-there-a-version-of-os-getcwd-that-doesnt-dereference-symlinks)

Comment: In summary:
To emulate `pwd -P`, the best option is `os.getcwd()`.
To emulate `pwd -L`, it is necessary to use either the shell, e.g. `subprocess.check_output('pwd', '-L')`, or a possibly inconsistent workaround such as `os.getenv('PWD')`.