# Prevent `os.chdir` from resolving symbolic link

Tags: python, linux, symlink

On all the machines on my cluster, my home directory is mounted from the NFS server as `/home/drive1/username`. On the NFS server, the folder `/home/drive1/username` is a symbolic link to `/drive1/username`.

Running:

```
$ python -c "import os; os.chdir('/home/drive1/username'); print(os.getcwd())"
```

on any machine *other than* the NFS server prints:

```
/home/drive1/username
```

but on the NFS server, the same command prints:

```
/drive1/username
```

Is there any way to prevent Python `os.chdir` from walking the symbolic link? This makes it difficult to specify the correct path when submit jobs from the NFS server to the worker nodes.

---

**Edit**:

Note that

```
cd /home/drive1/username
pwd
```

works as expected on all machines.

Comment: How is it meant to end up in the right directory if it doesn't follow the symbolic link? Does calling `os.getcwd()` in the script not bypass issue of it being a different location?

Comment: I just want it to work like `cd` and `pwd` in bash.

Comment: Seems https://stackoverflow.com/a/1545838/3527520 is the answer

Comment: This doesn't prevent you from having the same scripts running on both servers, only the scripts must not call `os.getcwd()`, but perhaps `my_own_getcwd()`.

Comment: I edited the post. The usecase is submitting jobs from the NFS server to worker nodes using a job scheduler such as Sun Grid Engine. I want to specify the full path to a script, but it's hard to do that from within Python.