# How to run a process in Java inside a symlink directory?

Tags: java, symlink

I need to run a native process from Java inside a symlink directory. Let's have following directory structure:

```
guido@Firefly:~/work$ tree
.
└── path
    └── to
        └── symlink -> /home/guido/work

3 directories, 0 files
```

I'm starting the Java application from the `~/work` directory and want to run the native process in the `~/work/path/to/symlink` directory.

However, if I use following Java code, **the symlink working directory resolves to the [real path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toRealPath-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-). Instead, I would like to run the command in the [absolute path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toAbsolutePath--).**

(Please mind, that `pwd` command is just for illustration and should be replaced with the "real" one (e.g. `go build` in my case)).

```java
File baseDir = new File("/home/guido/work");
File link = new File(baseDir, "path/to/symlink");
Files.createSymbolicLink(link.toPath(), baseDir.toPath());

Process process = new ProcessBuilder()
            .command("pwd")
            .directory(link)
            .start();

String output = getOutput(process);
System.out.println(output); // Prints: /home/guido/work
```

I was able to meet my needs with following workaround, but it looks stupid to start a *shell* just to be able to trigger a simple process in a specific directory. Plus, I lose platform independence.

```java
String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "cd " + link + " && pwd"};
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

String output = getOutput(process);
System.out.println(output); // Prints: /home/guido/work/path/to/symlink
```

Here, you can find a full example as a [unit test gist](https://gist.github.com/sw-samuraj/2c09157b8175b5a2365ae4c843690de0) with both solutions.

Comment: That's what symbolic links do. Resolve to the real path. Unclear what you're asking,

Comment: I'm asking _How to run a process in Java inside a symlink directory?_ `pwd` is just an example command, which I need to replace with the "real" one. I will modify a description a little bit.

Comment: If you use Path path = Files.createSymbolicLink(link.toPath(), baseDir.toPath()); and then File f = new File(path.toRealPath(LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS).toString()); you get what you expect but passing it to ProcessBuilder.directory seems to imply that ProcessBuilder follows symlinks as it won't stay in the link

Comment: @EJP I modified the description, so hopefully it's clearer that I'm not asking about behavior of symlinks.

Comment: Your test case works as expected/as you need on my mac. So, you may update your OS info to the Q.

Comment: @sujit Not sure what do you mean - those tests provided via _gist_ have exactly the same behavior on _Linux_ and on _macOS_ (10.13.3). So, the test `runCommandInShell` is passing, while the test `runCommandInSymlinkDir` is failing on assertion.

Comment: Tried，but not succeeded. Java always resolves the path to the real one. I think it might be an impossible mission only done in Java.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, you want the process to see the symlink as its working directory, and not the symlink target. I doubt that this is possible. A similar question has been asked for Python:

[Prevent `os.chdir` from resolving symbolic link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45336802)

First, the JVM doesn't resolve symlinks while running a process. After forking, it calls the `chdir()` system call in the child process, and that resolves the symlink:

https://github.com/dmlloyd/openjdk/blob/342a565a2da8abd69c4ab85e285bb5f03b48b2c9/src/java.base/unix/native/libjava/childproc.c#L362

Next, the working directory is returned by the `getcwd()` system call, which is guaranteed to return a path whose components are not symlinks:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html

Your workaround works for Bash, but it will not work for a process that calls `getcwd()`. Bash has its own version of `pwd`, which (I guess) also looks at the `PWD` environment variable (which is set by `cd`). If you modify `pwd` to `/usr/bin/pwd` in your workaround, it will display the symlink target.

Comment: That's a very good answer which explains the problem. However, it doesn't help with my problem: I'm writing a Java application (a _Gradle_ plugin) therefore I don't have any control over user's environment - I can do only OS checks and react on them.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer indicates there is probably no way to get this to work with symlinks, but perhaps there is another way. You could use a bind mount instead. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount or https://backdrift.org/how-to-use-bind-mounts-in-linux for more details. In short:

```
mkdir -p /path/to
mount -o bind /home/guido/work /path/to/symlink
```

This mounts a new file system in the path as a new view to the same directories and files. The Java application should resolve the path correctly. On the other hand a symlink is much more convenient and can be created without being root, so this is an exotic solution. Nevertheless, if it is important enough, perhaps it is the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

This was able to meet my needs with following workaround, but it looks stupid to start a shell just to be able to trigger a simple process in a specific directory. Plus, I lose platform independence.

```
String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "cd " + link + " && pwd"};
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

String output = getOutput(process);
System.out.println(output); // Prints: /home/guido/work/path/to/symlink
```

https://gist.github.com/sw-samuraj/2c09157b8175b5a2365ae4c843690de0